# Powershell try/catch/finally isn't executing right (or I've completely hosed it)

Tags: powershell

I have a script that checks for cyclic groups.
The script takes all groups in a domain (parent groups), checks the membership of those groups and adds any member with an objectClass of 'group' to an array (child groups).

The script then checks the child groups to see if the parent is a member of the child (yeah, it's allowed but still not a good idea).

I added a try/catch/finally block so I could get the actual group names instead of the truncated error message that PowerShell returns.

The problem is, the script stops at the first error it encounters instead of continuing on.

This is the first try/catch I've done, so please bear with me.

Here's the script:

```
$original_ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory

$domains = @('corp.com', 'dom1.corp.com', 'dom2.corp.com')


foreach($domain in $domains){
  Write-Host $domain -ForegroundColor Yellow
  $parents = Get-ADGroup -server $domain -Properties name,objectclass -Filter * #get all domain groups
  write-host $parents.count

  $table = @()
  $pGroupCount = @($parents).Count

  $record = @{
    'Parent' = ''
    'Child' = ''
    'Nester' = ''
  }

  foreach($parent in $parents){ 
    Write-Host $parent.name -ForegroundColor Green
```

The script works up to this point.

This is the part that fails-

```
    try { #get members in the parent that are groups
      $children = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $parent | Where-Object{$_.ObjectClass -eq 'group'} | Select-Object name,distinguishedName,objectClass  
      } catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember]{

        Write-Host $parent.name ' must be checked manually' -ForegroundColor blue -BackgroundColor Yellow
        $parent.distinguishedName | Out-String -Width 4096 | Out-File -FilePath "$env:USERPROFILE\desktop\$domain-manualCheck.txt" -Width 5120 -Append

    } finally {

    $pGroupCount = $pGroupCount - 1
    write-host $children.count ' - ' $children.name -ForegroundColor Gray
    Write-Host $pGroupCount ' groups to go' -foregroundColor yellow



  foreach($child in $children){ #get members in the children that are groups AND that have the same name as the parent
    $nested = Get-ADGroupMember $child.name | Where-Object {$_.objectClass -eq 'group' -and $_.name -eq $parent.name} 
    $nestedCount = @($nested).count

      if ($nestedCount -gt 0){
        foreach($nester in $nested){
          Write-Host $parent.name -ForegroundColor White
          Write-Host $nestedCount -ForegroundColor Magenta
          Write-Host $nester.name -ForegroundColor Cyan
          $record.'Parent' = $parent.name
          $record.'Child' = $child.name
          $record.'Nester' = $nester.name
          $objRecord = New-Object psobject -Property $record
          $table += $objRecord
        }
      }
    }
    $table | Export-Csv -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\desktop\$domain-Group-Report.csv" -NoTypeInformation
    $error | out-string -width 4096 | Out-File -FilePath "$env:USERPROFILE\desktop\$domain-Errors.txt" -Width 5120 -Append
  }
  }
  }
  $ErrorActionPreference = $original_ErrorActionPreference
```

As soon as the script hits the first group that has an issue, this is the error that's returned (#comments are added):

```
PS C:\Users\admin_j\Desktop> .\gtest.ps1
corp.com #current domain
283 #total group count
Exchange Servers #current group
6  -  Exchange Install Domain Servers Exchange Install Domain Servers Exchange Install Domain Servers Exchange Install Domain Servers Exchange Install Domain Servers #6 groups within the parent, groups are from sub-domains
Exchange Install Domain Servers
282  groups to go
Get-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'Exchange Install Domain Servers' under: 'DC=corp,DC=com'.
At C:\Users\admin_j\Desktop\gtest.ps1:46 char:15
+     $nested = Get-ADGroupMember $child.name | Where-Object $_.objectClass -eq ' ...
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Exchange Install Domain Servers:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Cannot find an object with identity: 'Exchange Install Domain Servers' under: 'DC=corp,DC=com'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember
```

Why, instead of writing the bad group (in this case 'Exchange Install Domain Servers' under: 'DC=corp,DC=com'.) to a file, did the script stop?  The group does indeed exist.

Should I add another block to catch any 'object not found' errors and send those to a file?

Thank you!

Comment: `catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember]` nope.  The *caught* object is going to be the exception being thrown. `GetADGroupMember` isn't an exception.  You can generalize by catching `System.Exception` instead, which may work for you.  When you specify the type in the catch, then if the exception isn't of that type, the catch doesn't execute.  You specified something that will never get thrown by the code you're calling, so your catch block wasn't executing.  You can also skip specifying a type so it executes every time no matter.

Comment: @Will- Thanks, that helped!  I changed the type to `[Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFound]` and it works now.

I also added another block to catch generic errors using `[Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADException]`.  For some reason I was getting an error that the command had completed successfully on the last element in the child array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Will's comment implies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45039301/powershell-try-catch-finally-isnt-executing-right-or-ive-completely-hosed-it/45041121#comment77052873_45039301), you have indeed hosed your `catch` clause by specifying a type literal not matching an exception you'd ever expect thrown.

The general syntax for a `catch` clause is as follows

```
catch [catch-type-list] <statement block>
```

Where `[catch-type-list]` is an optional list of exception types that the associated statement block will act as an exception handler for.

That means, that this catch clause:

```
catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMem‌​ber] {
    # ...
}
```

Will only ever handle errors caused by an exception of the type `[Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMem‌​ber]` - this is of course not an exception type, and so the associated statement block will never execute.

In order for your `catch` clause to make sense in this context, specify a relevant exception type:

```
try{
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $parent
}
catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADServerDownException]{
    # DC is unreachable, abort
}
catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityResolutionException]{
    # Group identity not resolved, add to list and continue
}
catch {
    # Something else, completely unforeseen, happened, you might want to re-throw and return from your function
}
```

The last `catch` clause, in which the type list has been omitted is known as a *general catch clause*, and will handle any exception that *didn't* match any of the preceding catch clauses.

Comment: Thanks Mathias.  I was able to get the try/catch working based on Will's suggestion.  I will say, you answer mad sense to me more than some of the articles I read.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Joe-L_177 Happy it made some sense ^_^